# jQuery Scroll Buttons that are limited by the amount of content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am new to javascript and jQuery and I have an issue with the code that I wrote, it scrolls after the content and I cannot think of how to get it to be limited by the amount of content.

Here is the jQuery:

```
jQuery('.scrollup').click(function(event){
    jQuery(".entry-content-area").animate({ "margin-top": "+=150px" },'100');
});
jQuery('.scrolldown').click(function(event){
    jQuery('.entry-content-area').animate({ "margin-top": "-=150px" },'100');
});
```

Here is the HTML (it's for WordPress):

```
<div class="entry-content-box">
    <div class="entry-containment-area">
        <div class="entry-content-area">
            <p>CONTENT HERE</p>
        </div><!-- entry-content-area -->
    </div><!-- entry-containment-area -->
    <div class="scroll-area">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <button class="scrolldown"></button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button class="scrollup">
                </button>
            </li>
       </ul>
    </div><!-- scroll-area -->
</div><!-- entry-content-box -->
```

As you can see it only moves the css `margin-top` 150px up or down, but this is not linked to the actual amount of text. How would I recode this to make it so that it scrolls but it limited by the amount of text?

Thanks!

Comment: You can measure the total height of the block all the content is in and restrict scrolling if the top-position is higher than the height of that block...

Comment: The issue is that it is dynamic, being generated by wordpress, so I don't know how I would measure the height when it changes per page, if I'm understanding what you're saying. What would the code look life for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to animate the `scrollTop` property, rather than the margin top. Assuming you have an overflow container with some text that is causing the container to overflow, you can animate the scroll top property so that the content moves within the scroll container.

```
jQuery('.scrollup').click(function(event){
    jQuery(".entry-content-area").animate({ "scrollTop": "-=150px" },'100');
});
jQuery('.scrolldown').click(function(event){
    jQuery('.entry-content-area').animate({ "scrollTop": "+=150px" },'100');
});
```

Comment: Yep, that is it. Combined with the css `overflow-y: hidden;` for the `entry-content-area` tag means I now have a scrollable scrollbar-less textarea that is restricted by the amount of text, exactly what I need. You're the best!